# asymptotic behavior of $y'= \sqrt{-a/y^2+by^2-cy^4+d}$ at x=infinity?

Tags: asymptotics

Asymptotic behaviour of $y'= \sqrt{-a/y^2+by^2-cy^4+d}$   at x=infinity ?

Boundary condition is given by $y'(\infty)=0$

I can find the solution numerically but I cant find the asymptotic behaviour analytically, any help ?

Comment: You mean you have to find it analytically in terms of $a,b,c,d$?  Warning:  it's going to get messy!

Comment: yes that would be preferable, at least is it possible to know the leading behaviour? like x^(?) ?